# I am getting ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list on my code

Tags: python

```
code_arr=[]
for i in word_tokenize(student_code):
  code_arr.append(i)
print(code_arr)
print(len(code_arr))

codet_arr=[]
for i in word_tokenize(teacher_code):
  codet_arr.append(i)
print(codet_arr)
print(len(codet_arr))

for code_s in code_arr:
  for code_t in codet_arr:
    if code_s==code_t:
      code_arr.remove(code_t)
    else:
      continue
```

The above code gives below error:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-4fe8ea0c7232> in <module>()
      2   for code_t in codet_arr:
      3     if code_s==code_t:
----> 4       code_arr.remove(code_t)
      5     else:
      6       continue

ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list
```

Comment: As I mentioned in a comment to the accepted answer, you need to clarify what you expect with repeated tokens in the two lists. Do you want to remove from the first list the number of matching repeats? Or all repeats of any token found in the second list? Or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing the content of the arrays it's difficult to duplicate but I suspect your problem is in modifying the content of an array that you're iterating over.

For clarity, I tend to build a set of values that I want to remove, then remove them in a separate loop, viz...

```
to_remove = set()
for code_s in code_arr:
  for code_t in codet_arr:
    if code_s == code_t:
      to_remove.add(code_t)

for code in to_remove:
  code_arr.remove(code)
```

Debugging is easier too as you can check the codes to be removed before removing them.

Ps. You don't need the 'else continue' on the end of a loop.

Comment: There was, briefly, another answer here that I liked.  Essentially, use a copy of the array that you're removing from so use: `for code_s in code_arr[:]:`.

Comment: The handling of repeated elements probably has to be more elaborate, although there is no clue in the OP as to what the expectation is. Your code will only remove an element once from `code_arr`, no matter how many times it appears in each list. But it's quite possible that the intent was to remove from `code_arr` the number of repetitions of each element as are found in `codet_arr`. Or it's possible that the intent was to remove from `code_arr` all the repetitions of any element found in `codet_arr`. Since the original code won't work, it's not really a reliable guide.

Comment: Good point.  Sometimes it's difficult to work out the intended semantics of non-working code...

Answer (score -1):

I think this will work :

```
for i in code_arr:
  while i in code_t:
    code_t.remove(i)
print(code_t)
```